Error installing NUGET package when the project is in Google drive folder (0b .nupkg file)
Cannot install any NUGET package from visual studio 2022, if my projects folder located in google drive folder.
Tried to move to local folder (documents) and it's working well.
For some reason *.nupkg file is 0 byte length. All other package files are ok, have some weight. Clearing cache didn't help.
I need to use google drive. Copying every time to/from local is a problem.
update:
error log (at least part of it)
System.IO.InvalidDataException: Central Directory corrupt. ---> System.IO.IOException: An attempt was made to move the file pointer before the beginning of the file.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.SeekCore(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Seek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin)
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory()
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.Init(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen)
   at NuGet.Packaging.PackageArchiveReader..ctor(String filePath, IFrameworkNameProvider frameworkProvider, IFrameworkCompatibilityProvider compatibilityProvider)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NuGet.Packaging.PackageArchiveReader..ctor(String filePath, IFrameworkNameProvider frameworkProvider, IFrameworkCompatibilityProvider compatibilityProvider)
   at NuGet.ProjectManagement.FolderNuGetProject.<DeletePackage>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<DeletePackageAsync>d__104.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync>d__87.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync>d__86.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync>d__85.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.NuGetProjectManagerService.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<<ExecuteActionsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.NuGetProjectManagerService.<CatchAndRethrowExceptionAsync>d__32.MoveNext()

Did anyone had this issue ?! Any solution for it?
Thanks

How do you connect your projects located in google drive from visual studio? like Repositories?

No, simple folder.
My guess is that its a network drive problem. (google drive folder comes like a network drive)

After some research and help from microsoft the fix is simple - removing packages.config from source folder will fix the issue. But packages will be installed not per project.
